# VSCode Run and Debug ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-debugger, modulenotfounderror

I have a project which I am writing using **VSCode (WSL, venv)** and am trying to debug my **test_abc.py** code.
However I am getting **ModuleNotFound** error, in the line where I am importing settings from **server.config** file (`from server.config import settings`).

My project structure is:

main folder

- server

  - config.py
- tests

  - graphql

    - test_abc.py

Testing extension of VSCode works perfectly fine.
So I guess Run and Debug somehow can not browse the folders above the file.

Below is my **launch.json** file:

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Python: Current File (WSL)",
          "type": "python",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${file}",
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "console": "integratedTerminal",
          "justMyCode": true,
      }
  ]
}
```

Below is my **settings.json** file:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
}
```

I have tried to add `"env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}` to **launch.json** but it makes Running worse, when I try to Run the code, Run and Debug prints nothing, just finishes with no result or error. So I am quite confused what is going on there.

Would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your `PYTHONPATH` configuration like that:

```json
"PYTHONPATH": "${env:PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}:${workspaceFolder}/server:${workspaceFolder}/tests"
```

It appends your two subdirs to your existing `PYTHONPATH` (`${env:PYTHONPATH}:`).

You can then try to keep your imports as they are (it should work as `workspaceFolder` is added to the path) or write more directly (if you have no module names conflicts of course):

```py
from server.config import settings
```